# payload layout of inspect element in python

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, instagram, web-inspector, developer-payload

Hi I want to get the data from payload header of inspect element of Instagram website I have tried a lot of things but I can't fetch the data from the payload header of inspect element I want to you to help me that is there any way to access to the data of payload header of inspect element